# Yesterday's Date For Different timezone is Incorrect

Tags: swift, date

I have a function that calculates yesterday's date in Central Europe.
The date value in `yesDay = 2020-11-03 00:31:25 +0000` is always correct.
After `yesDay` goes through the date formatter (at the return statement) it displays yesDay `- 1` or `2020-11-02`.  I think `yesDay` is of type Date so I can't just use a string operation to wack off the date from the other data. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
func yesterdayDate() -> String {
    
    var dayComponent = DateComponents()
    var calendar = Calendar.current

    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Paris")!
    dayComponent.day = -1
    let yesDay =  calendar.date(byAdding: dayComponent, to: Date())!
                              
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter.string(from: yesDay)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set timeZone on your DateFormatter too.